# Genetic Recombination and Mutation

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

Can genetic recombination yield mutation depending on the new DNA that is incorporated into the genome? I would say yes because when something foreign comes in, the genome is bound to not function properly.

Comment: Can you please try to clarify the question? My answer and @canadianer comment underneath shows that the question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "new DNA that is incorporated into the genome", it suggests that you misunderstand what genetic recombination. You might to ensure you really understand this concept before going any further.

Mutation rate and recombination rate tend to covary throughout the genome ([Lercher and Hurst 2002](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952502026690)). So, yes processes leading to recombination events also tend to cause mutational events.

Comment: Recombination can be used to insert new DNA into a genome. For example: lambda phage or genetic engineering.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what most people think of when using the term genetic recombination and the OP did not comment on that.